# Unable to set unlimited File Index using SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have used logger and my logs are generated having more than 3 gb. So i decided to use RollingFileAppender with properties MaxFileSize and MaxBackupIndex is 1000 but problem came at file name because file extension after reaching the size limit generates as File not .log. Also I tried different RollingPolicy with SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy but no success.

I want my logs should be generated unlimited when size exceed 100mb and each log file should have extension as .log and file pattern should be applied.

Kindly help me with writing suitable log4.properties for my above scenario.